# Xamrin Grid get height by text size

Tags: view, xamarin, xamarin.forms, text-size

In Xamarin Forms I use `Grid` to show some icons as `Button` and Text as `Label`.

I want my Icons to fit to default grid size, to do so I need to know what is the height of the `Grid`. But all the height values of `Grid` are 0.

My question are: how cant I get any Height size of this grid? Can I figure the height by text size?

P.S. I don't want to set specific height value for `Grid`, I want it to remain default.

Comment: Did you ever get to figure out your problem?

Comment: All grid sizes are calculated after rendering so I don't know the size before it built. I use OnSizeAllocated function that gives me the sizes.

Comment: Alright. Glad to know you worked it out. You can always override OnAppearing as well from where you can get the size of the `View`.